VS2017 EF6 Can not add a connection to mysql database
In VS2017 I use Microsoft EF6 to connect to a mysql database.
When I try to add a new item 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' in my application 'APP1' there is no way to set up a connection to the mysql database.

I have an existing application 'APP2', where I can update my 'DataModel.edmx' view by clicking 'update model from database'. Everything works fine, I can update tables, add new ones and so on.
Both apps have the same NuGetPackages installed and reference exactly the same dll's concerning mysql, dotnet and entityframework.
So there must be a valid connection to the database.
In detail:
MSEntity Framework 6.4.4 (\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll)
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7
MySqlConnector 9.0.0
MySql.Data 9.0.0 (\packages\MySql.Data.9.0.0\lib\net462\MySql.Data.dll)
MySql.Data.EntityFramework 9.0.0 
(\packages\MySql.Data.EntityFramework.9.0.0\lib\net462\MySql.Data.EntityFramework.dll)
Target Framework ist .NET Framework 4.7.2
I guess it should be allowed to handle two 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' in one app at a time. So I tried to add a new 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' in APP2, where the existing model works fine, but received the same error.
I sure know there is a lot of answers concerning the SSPI call exception but they didnt solve my issue.
Very helpful would be to get to know the inner exception. In the windows event viewer I could not find it.
Any help will be appreciated.
added 2024-10-28
Opening a connection in code works fine, there is no exception...
try
        {
            var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


SSPI is an authentication methid for windows integrated authentication. Unless you have mysql enterprise, that can't work with mysql. Did you try to configure integrated authentication with mysql?

@Shadow Thanks, no I did not try to configure anything concerning authentification. I will concentrate my search in that direction.

Does anybody know how I can view this inner exception ?

Ok, I got the problem solved.
It ended up in using a certain combination f drivers.
EntityFramework 6.44, MySql for visual studio 1.2.9, MySqlConnector 9.0.0add References MySql.Data and MySql.Data.EntityFramework.The SSPI error was gone, I can update the existing entities from the database and also add a now DatabaseModel from any mySql database. Took me two day to find that solution, I hope it helps someone. Seems to be a real rare combination ove drivers getting ef6 to work on mySql.

One thing I forgot: MySql.Data and MySql.Data.EntityFramework are installed via NuGet packages. Be sure to install the same version 9.0.0 as MySqlConnector. The dlls in the NuGet packages folder of the project should automatically be referenced.

I got it fixed and I will answer my own question, beacause this is absoluteley helpful for someone struggling with EF6 and the error message 'a call to SSPI failed' does really not give you any idea where top search for!
It ended up to be just a matter of configuration.Several combinations of 'MySql for Visualstudio' and 'MySqlConnector' do not fit together and throw this exception when using the EF6 model creation wizard.
I tried this on a different PC, installed mysql server with all the drivers and could again reproduce this error for several combinations.
If you want to use EF6 with VS2017 for mySql server 8, please use the following setup:
MySql server 8
MySql for Visual Studio 1.2.9 (!)
MySql Connector/NET 9.0.0 (!)
NuGet package EntityFramework 6.44
NuGet package MySql.Data 9.0.0 (same version as MySql Connector/NET)
NuGet package MySql.Data.EntityFramework 9.0.0 ( " )
